# Error in Vue when trying to call bulma.sass file

Tags: vue.js, sass, bulma

first time asking a question here, so I apologize if this is incorrect - I'll get better!

I'm following along with a Vue.js tutorial, and am trying to install and call Bulma via an "@import '../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass' file.

I'm able to view my vue "home" page, but once I add a "lang=sass" to my style tag, I keep getting the following error:

> > "Failed to compile.
> >
> > ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
> > Module build failed: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
> > at Object.loader (/Users/Dave/compare-vue/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:25:24)
> > @
> > ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
> > 4:14-384 13:3-17:5 14:22-392   @ ./src/App.vue   @ ./src/main.js   @multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
> > webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js"

Here is the code from my "app.vue" page:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style lang="sass">
@import '../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass'

#app
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
  text-align: center
  color: #2c3e50
  margin-top: 60px
</style>
```

If I remove the "style" tag, the page loads and displays correctly, but then any changes I make on my styles.scss page obviously don't take effect as I belive I haven't called the SASS language.

I'm currently running node v 14.15.4 and npm v 6.14.10. I've tried everything I can see, from adjusting the package.json, etc. I can't contact the creator of the tutorial, and I really can't figure out anything else to do for the life of me. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of importing it as `../node_modules/bulma/bulma.scss` try importing using the package name, suppose the package name is `bulma` then import it as `@bulma/bulma.scss`

Comment: I tried this too, still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Vue-CLI sets up your project with CSS support out of the box, but requires an extra step for Sass. Looks like you still need to install the sass preprocessor:

`npm install -D sass-loader sass`

Look here for more info:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't do anything. Still have the same error. I just tried to install via the Sass site, and get the error that the directory already exists. For some reason it's there, but when I call it via the style tag I encounter the error.

Comment: Have you tried with `lang='scss'`? Also, make sure your webpack is configured correctly: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass

Comment: Adding the lang='scss' tag changes the format of the code, but not the result. Where exactly would that "webpack config:" file be located? Theres a lot of webpack config that I'm seeing in all of the files that the vue installation added.

Comment: In following the error to my /node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js folder, and then looking at the JS lines, it says

" * The sass-loader makes node-sass and dart-sass available to webpack modules.
"@this {object}"
" @param {string} content."

I'm thinking this is a webpack issue, but I've tried a clean remove and install of the webpacks and to try and resolve any conflicting issues between versions. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues with the sass-loader with vuejs on a mac...

I tried following this guide: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html  - had issues with uncompatible webpack packages

Saw that they supported different versions of node on a mac so fixed it like this

- Dropped node to version 15 using n package
  `n 15`
- Installed sass-loader v 10.0.5
  `npm install -D sass-loader@10.0.5 node-sass`
- Checked that `<script lang="scss">` was added to the App.vue file
- `yarn serve` now works as expected and creates a css file from sass

This might change as new versions of the packages become available.

** There might be better ways to change node versions (please comment)